Reactflow, how to make custom nodes as droppable areas for draggable elements
I want a workflow feature, using react flow, but I want to be able to drag and drop components into each node. Maybe this is possible somehow by creating custom nodes with react flow?
But I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around how I could make custom nodes as droppable areas for draggable elements.
Any thoughts are greatly appreciated.
In Reactflow Drag and Drop option, i want to drop custom node from sidebar to another node (like specific for drop),don't want to drop anywhere on the right pane , want to specific the dropping area
const onDrop = useCallback(
  (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const type = event.dataTransfer.getData('application/reactflow');

    if (typeof type === 'undefined' || !type) {
      return;
    }

    if (type === "AddNode") { 
      const position = screenToFlowPosition({
        x: event.clientX,
        y: event.clientY,
      });

      const newNode = {
        id: getId(),
        type,
        position,
        data: { label: `${type} node` },
      };

      setNodes((nds) => nds.concat(newNode));
    }
  },
  [screenToFlowPosition]
);


You can use Dropzone.
import React, { useState, DragEvent } from 'react';
import { Paper, Typography, IconButton, Divider, Fab, Box, styled } from '@mui/material';
import DeleteIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Delete';
import SettingsIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Settings';
import { Handle, Position } from 'reactflow';
import { AddToPhotos } from '@mui/icons-material';

interface TextNodeProps {
    data: {
        label: string;
        isSelected: boolean;
    };
}

const InputWrapper = styled(Box)(({ theme }) => ({
    flexGrow: 1,
    borderRadius: '15px',
    boxShadow: '0px 0px 5px 0px #6950e8',
    border: '3px solid #3f3378',
    color: '#3f3378',
    backgroundColor: '#d3d3d3',
    padding: theme.spacing(1),
    position: 'relative',
    marginBottom: theme.spacing(2),
}));

const RemoveButton = styled(IconButton)(({ theme }) => ({
    display: 'none',
    position: 'absolute',
    top: theme.spacing(1),
    right: theme.spacing(1),
    '&:hover': {
        display: 'flex',
        color: '#3D3D3D',
    },
}));

const TextNode: React.FC<TextNodeProps> = ({ data }) => {
    const { isSelected } = data;
    const [inputs, setInputs] = useState([{ id: 1, value: 'oie' }]);
    const [isDropzoneActive, setDropzoneActive] = useState(false);

    const handleRemoveInput = (id: number) => {
        setInputs(inputs.filter(input => input.id !== id));
    };

    const handleAddInput = (newInput: string) => {
        const newId = inputs.length > 0 ? inputs[inputs.length - 1].id + 1 : 1;
        setInputs([...inputs, { id: newId, value: newInput }]);
    };

    const onDrop = (event: DragEvent<HTMLDivElement>) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        const nodeType = event.dataTransfer.getData("nodeType");
        handleAddInput(nodeType);
        setDropzoneActive(false);
    };

    const onDragOver = (event: DragEvent<HTMLDivElement>) => {
        event.preventDefault();
    };

    const onDragEnter = () => {
        setDropzoneActive(true);
    };

    const onDragLeave = () => {
        setDropzoneActive(false);
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <Handle
                type="target"
                position={Position.Left}
                style={{
                    background: '#000',
                    width: '12px',
                    height: '12px',
                    borderRadius: '6px',
                }}
                onConnect={(params) => console.log('handle onConnect', params)}
            />

            <Paper
                elevation={0}
                style={{
                    width: 300,
                    padding: '10px 20px',
                    backgroundColor: '#333',
                    color: 'white',
                    borderRadius: '20px',
                    border: isSelected ? '3px solid #3f3378' : '1px solid #4a4a4a',
                }}
                onDrop={(e) => { e.stopPropagation(); onDrop(e); }}
                onDragOver={onDragOver}
                onDragEnter={onDragEnter}
                onDragLeave={onDragLeave}
            >
                <div style={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'space-between', alignItems: 'center', width: '100%' }}>
                    <Typography variant="subtitle1">Mensagens</Typography>
                    <div>
                        <IconButton size="small" style={{ color: 'white', marginLeft: 'auto' }}>
                            <SettingsIcon />
                        </IconButton>
                        <IconButton size="small" style={{ color: 'rgb(248 113 113)' }}>
                            <DeleteIcon />
                        </IconButton>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <Divider style={{ backgroundColor: 'gray', margin: '5px 0' }} />

                {isDropzoneActive && (
                    <Typography style={{ textAlign: "center", color: "#fff" }}>Drop here</Typography>
                )}

                {inputs.map((input) => (
                    <InputWrapper key={input.id}>
                        <Typography style={{ color: '#3f3378', fontSize: '12px' }}>
                            {input.value}
                        </Typography>
                        <RemoveButton onClick={() => handleRemoveInput(input.id)}>
                            <DeleteIcon />
                        </RemoveButton>
                    </InputWrapper>
                ))}

                <Fab
                    color="primary"
                    aria-label="add"
                    style={{
                        backgroundColor: isSelected ? '#3f3378' : '#333',
                        margin: '10px auto',
                        display: 'block',
                    }}
                    onClick={() => handleAddInput('Novo Item')}
                >
                    <AddToPhotos />
                </Fab>
            </Paper>

            <Handle
                type="source"
                position={Position.Right}
                style={{
                    background: '#000',
                    width: '12px',
                    height: '12px',
                    borderRadius: '6px',
                }}
                onConnect={(params) => console.log('handle onConnect', params)}
            />
        </div>
    );
};

export default TextNode;

